# What are the versions of omnet,veins,sumo that support the definition of signal MIXIM_SIGNAL_MOBILITY_CHANGE_NAME in UVCAST?

Tags: signals, omnet++, veins, sumo, mixim

When I use the following programmed line in my code When I am studying UV-CAST Protocol .
Define_Module(UVCAST);
const simsignalwrap_t
UVCAST::mobilityStateChangedSignal=simsignalwrap_t(MIXIM_SIGNAL_MOBILITY_CHANGE_NAME);
Should I import one of mixim versions to omnet version that I am working on it ?
my current version is omnet version 5.0,veins 4.4,sumo 0.24?
or should I change the version of omnet and I use omnet 4.4.1?
or should I only include veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h in UVCAST.cc?
thanks .
I hope your reply.